# Не работает функция добавления в Избранное

Tags: java, android, классы

Не пойму каким методом и как вызывать добавление объекта в избранное и его удаление. Если я должен использовать код Favorite.addFavorite(...);, то где мне его прописать нужно? и что нужно подавать ему на вход сюда в скобки: addFavorite(); Первый раз при открытии вкладки с избранным - она открывается и внутри пусто как и должно быть, потому что ничего не добавлялось.

Если в активити, вставить метод на слушатель кнопки: Favorite.addFavorite(сюда пробывал подать строку с названием объекта); то при открытии вкладки с избранным, приложение крашит, и помогает очистка кеша или запуск метода Favorite.removeFavorite(...);

**содержимое CacheManager.java**

```
public class CacheManager {

private static File root;

public static void initialize(final Context context) {
    root = context.getExternalCacheDir();
}

public static File getRoot() {
    return root;
}
```

}

**содержимое Favorites.java**

```
public class Favorites {

private static List<String> favoriteUrls = null;

private static File getFavoritesPath() {
    return new File(CacheManager.getRoot(), "favorites");
}

public static void load() {
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
            favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (favorites == null)
                return;
            for (String favorite : favorites)
                favoriteUrls.add(favorite);
        }
    });
}

public static List<Station> getFavorites() {
    final List<Station> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String url : favoriteUrls)
        favorites.add(Directory.getStation(url));
    Station.sort(favorites);
    return favorites;
}

public static void addFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (!favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.add(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

public static void removeFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.remove(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

protected static void commit() {
    final String[] urls = favoriteUrls.toArray(new String[favoriteUrls.size()]);
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).commit(urls);
}
}
```

**содержимое Directory.java:**

```
public class Directory {
private static final String TAG = Log.buildTag(Directory.class);
private static List<Station> stations = null;

private static Map<String, Station> stationIndex = new HashMap<>();

public static void loadStations(final Context context) {
    stations = new ArrayList<>();

    final AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

    String paths[] = new String[0];
    try {
        paths = assetManager.list("stations");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error loading stations", e);
        return;
    }

    for (String path : paths) {
        if (!path.endsWith(".json"))
            continue;
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Station>>() {}.getType();
        List<Station> chunk = null;
        try {
            chunk = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("stations/" + path), "UTF-8"), listType);
            stations.addAll(chunk);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error loading station: %s", e, path);
        }
    }

    Station.sort(stations);

    indexStations(stations);

}

private static void indexStations(final List<Station> stations) {
    stationIndex.clear();

    for (Station station : stations) {
        stationIndex.put(station.getStationUrl(), station);
    }
}

public static List<Station> getStations() {
    return stations;
}

public static Station getStation(final String url) {
    return stationIndex.get(url);
}
}
```

Comment: Судя по коду нужно передать туда url-адрес в виде строки (который, видимо можно получить из `station.getStationUrl()`. А вообще из приведённого кода не видно всей картины - эти классы требуют инициализации с контекстом, делается ли она у Вас и во вкладке избранного, какая именно ошибка выстреливает?

Comment: @woesss, E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.sample.radio.pro.data.Station.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.sample.radio.pro.ui.DirectoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DirectoryAdapter.java:51)........

Comment: Я так понял, что подаю на вход в Favorite.addFavorite(...) что то неправильно.. По этому при последующем открытии вкладки с избранным, адаптер не может построить список, так как данные не правильные.

Comment: Весь стек ошибки добавьте в вопрос. Чей это код? Если библиотека какая-то тоже стоит указать в вопросе. Очень похоже что этот кусок кода для он-лайн радио со списком станций в ассетах и добавлением их же в избранное - это вообще то, что Вы хотите?

Comment: @woesss, напишите полноценный ответ ниже к вопросу. Мне помогло то что вы написали (Судя по коду нужно передать туда url-адрес в виде строки (который, видимо можно получить из station.getStationUrl(). )
Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по коду нужно передать в метод `Favorites.addFavorite(...)` url-адрес в виде строки (который, видимо можно получить из `station.getStationUrl()`).